# Groovy: How to Refer to a Super Class Method from a Closure in a Subclass Method?

Tags: groovy

Given the following setup in `test.groovy`:

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String ... args) {
    new Child().foo()
  }

  public static class Parent {
    def foo() {
      println 'from parent'
    }
  }

  public static class Child extends Parent {
    def foo() {
      // def superRef = super.&foo  // needed to try what’s commented below
      def myClosure = {
        super.foo()  // doesn’t work, neither does anything of the following:
        // this.super.foo()
        // Child.super.foo()
        // Child.this.super.foo()
        // superRef()
        println 'from child'
      }
      myClosure()
    }
  }
}
```

When I run `groovy test.groovy` (with Groovy 2.5.4 and at least all other versions I’ve tried), then I get the following error:

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static Main.foo() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: any(), find(), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), is(java.lang.Object), any(groovy.lang.Closure), find(groovy.lang.Closure)
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static Main.foo() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: any(), find(), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), is(java.lang.Object), any(groovy.lang.Closure), find(groovy.lang.Closure)
    at Main$Child.methodMissing(test.groovy)
    at Main$Child$_foo_closure1.doCall(test.groovy:16)
    at Main$Child$_foo_closure1.doCall(test.groovy)
    at Main$Child.foo(test.groovy:23)
    at Main$Child$foo.call(Unknown Source)
    at Main.main(test.groovy:3)
```

How can I refer to a super class method (`Parent.foo`) from a closure (`myClosure`) enclosed by the corresponding method of the subclass (`Child.foo`)?

(background: the closure in my actual code is needed to do something like `myCloseable.withCloseable { super.foo(); … }`)

Answer (score 1):

as soon as closure  - it's another class (in terms of java), and you can't access super method from another class.

IHMO the only way:

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String ... args) {
    new Child().foo()
  }

  public static class Parent {
    def foo() {
      println 'from parent'
    }
  }

  public static class Child extends Parent {
    def superFoo(){
        super.foo()
    }
    def foo() {
      def myClosure = {
        superFoo()
        println 'from child'
      }
      myClosure()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this workaround, +1. I still wonder if there is not a more elegant solution out there? I understand that a closure is another class instance but since I can access other fields/methods/… outside of the closure, why shouldn’t I be able to access a super method?

Comment: you can't do it in java - so you can't do it in groovy. just try to convert your code to java and instead of closure use Runnable implementation -> compile error. maybe you could redesign methods/closure/inheritance to make it elegant....

Comment: That’s not correct, it _is_ possible in Java. Try the sample code with the implementation of `Child.foo` being the following: `Runnable myClosure = () -> { Child.super.foo(); System.err.println("from child"); }; myClosure.run();`